# How to debug cqlsh?

Tags: debugging, autocomplete, cassandra, cqlsh

I need to find out how cqlsh does the autocomplete because I want to include a custom compaction strategy in the autocomplete for the create table statement. I usually do this by putting a breakpoint somewhere in the code and then following the flow. But I'm not sure how to do this with cqlsh since I don't see the main method. How can I debug cqlsh to better understand where I need to implement this?
Probably not relevant, but I'm using v3.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cqlsh is a python tool, It located at `$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cqlsh.py`**

If you want to add custom compaction strategy to cqlsh, you have to edit it's dependency file located at `$CASSANDRA_HOME//pylib/cqlshlib/cqlhandling.py`

Find the `available_compaction_classes` field and add yours.

```
available_compaction_classes = (
    'LeveledCompactionStrategy',
    'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy',
    'DateTieredCompactionStrategy',
    'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy',
    'MyCompactionStrategy'
)
```

Here i have added `MyCompactionStrategy`.

Now save the changes and relogin, you will get autocomplete for compaction

```
cassandra@cqlsh:titan> CREATE TABLE test (id int primary key, data text) WITH compaction = {'class': '
DateTieredCompactionStrategy  LeveledCompactionStrategy     MyCompactionStrategy          SizeTieredCompactionStrategy  TimeWindowCompactionStrategy
```

Comment: Oh wow, you saved me a lot of work because I don't know how to work with Python (yet). Thanks, man!

Answer (score 2):

cqlsh is written using python, hence you can use any python editor to debug the code. One such python editor which I'm using is **JetBrains PyCharm** You can open the cqlsh.py script from "Cassandra installed directory\bin" in this editor and run the cqlsh.py in debug mode. While running/debugging use the console view to give the input. By the way I am using PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

cqlsh command have option --debug that help you to debug it in detail and get more verbose information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
cqlsh:demo> TRACING ON
Now Tracing is enabled
```

sometimes this level of logging is sufficient in debugging.