# Docker compose "condition: service_completed_successfully" causing cassandra container to exit with status 2

Tags: docker-compose, cassandra, dockerfile

Here's my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  dd_cassandra:
    container_name: dd_cassandra
    image: ecr.org_name.info/builder-cassandra-it:2023-11-16-0919-6b9ecd95
    volumes:
      - "./common/cassandra:/lua/cassandra_setup:rw"
      - "../services_root:/services_root:ro"
      - "../services_root/services/orchestrationplan/common/plans:/tmp/plans:ro"
      - "../services_root/services/orchestrationplan/common/building_blocks:/tmp/templates:ro"
      - "../services_root/services/billingv4/output_plan_rules:/tmp/output_plan_rules:ro"
    environment:
      WORKSPACE: "/tmp"
      SERVICES_ROOT_DIR: "/services_root"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "1024M"
      DOCKER_PLANS_DIR: "/tmp/plans"
      DOCKER_TEMPLATES_DIR: "/tmp/templates"
      DOCKER_OUTPUT_PLAN_RULES_DIR: "/tmp/output_plan_rules"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "512M"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "cqlsh", "-u", "cassandra", "-p", "cassandra" ]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 60
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"

  cassandra_populator:
    container_name: cassandra_populator
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./it/cassandra/Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ecr.lotusflare.info/builder-cassandra-it:2023-11-16-0919-6b9ecd95
    depends_on:
      dd_cassandra:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - "./common/cassandra:/lua/cassandra_setup:rw"
      - "../services_root:/services_root:ro"
      - "../services_root/services/orchestrationplan/common/plans:/tmp/plans:ro"
      - "../services_root/services/orchestrationplan/common/building_blocks:/tmp/templates:ro"
      - "../services_root/services/billingv4/output_plan_rules:/tmp/output_plan_rules:ro"
      - "./integration-test-config.lua:/tmp/integration-test-config.lua:ro"
    environment:
      WORKSPACE: "/tmp"
      SERVICES_ROOT_DIR: "/services_root"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "1024M"
      DOCKER_PLANS_DIR: "/tmp/plans"
      DOCKER_TEMPLATES_DIR: "/tmp/templates"
      DOCKER_OUTPUT_PLAN_RULES_DIR: "/tmp/output_plan_rules"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "512M"

  dd_dew:
    container_name: dd_dew
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./it/Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: ecr.org_name.info/openresty:2023-11-16-0128-6a9e2f9c
    environment:
      ACCESS_LOG: "stderr"
      ERROR_LOG: "stderr info"
      MNT_DIR: "/mnt/lua"
    depends_on:
       cassandra_populator
         condition: service_completed_successfully
    volumes:
      - "./integration-test-config.lua:/mnt/lua/config.lua:ro"
      - "../.luacheckrc:/mnt/lua/.luacheckrc"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "9909:9909"
```

Under the `dd_dew` container, there's a condition:

```
 depends_on:
   cassandra_populator:
     condition: service_completed_successfully
```

If I remove the `condition: service_completed_successfully`, cassandra_populator exits successfully with status 0 which is a desired scenario.

However, on using this condition, it exits with **status 2**.

The dockerfile for cassandra_populator looks like:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

COPY ./it/common/cassandra/cassandra-setup.sh /
RUN chmod +x /cassandra-setup.sh

CMD ["/cassandra-setup.sh"]
```

and the cassandra-setup.sh script creates tables/schemas inside the dd_cassandra container by remotely accessing the dd_cassandra and running the cqlsh command.

Here are the last few logs:

```
cassandra_populator  | 
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [MutationStage-1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,036 ColumnFamilyStore.java:2252 - Truncating billingv4.rules
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [MutationStage-1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,037 ColumnFamilyStore.java:878 - Enqueuing flush of rules: 55.572KiB (0%) on-heap, 0.000KiB (0%) off-heap
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,041 Memtable.java:471 - Writing Memtable-rules@348774377(34.163KiB serialized bytes, 38 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit), flushed range = (min(-9223372036854775808), max(9223372036854775807)]
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,042 Memtable.java:500 - Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/billingv4/rules-a1528e10d02a11eeb8424d05e7bf37da/nb-9-big-Data.db (31.202KiB) for commitlog position CommitLogPosition(segmentId=1708505613175, position=198144)
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [MutationStage-1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,052 ColumnFamilyStore.java:2289 - Truncating billingv4.rules with truncatedAt=1708505638052
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [MutationStage-1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,054 ColumnFamilyStore.java:2741 - Truncation is dropping 1 sstables and keeping 0 due to sstable.maxDataAge > truncatedAt
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,057 SSTable.java:111 - Deleting sstable: /var/lib/cassandra/data/billingv4/rules-a1528e10d02a11eeb8424d05e7bf37da/nb-9-big
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [MutationStage-1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,057 ColumnFamilyStore.java:878 - Enqueuing flush of local: 0.576KiB (0%) on-heap, 0.000KiB (0%) off-heap
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:2] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,060 Memtable.java:471 - Writing Memtable-local@2033151335(0.091KiB serialized bytes, 1 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit), flushed range = (min(-9223372036854775808), max(9223372036854775807)]
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:2] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,061 Memtable.java:500 - Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/nb-26-big-Data.db (0.063KiB) for commitlog position CommitLogPosition(segmentId=1708505613175, position=198322)
dd_cassandra         | INFO  [MutationStage-1] 2024-02-21 08:53:58,070 ColumnFamilyStore.java:2316 - Truncate of billingv4.rules is complete
cassandra_populator exited with code 2
service "cassandra_populator" didn't complete successfully: exit 2
```

Here's how my *cassandra-setup.sh* bash script looks like:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  # Set default values
  SERVICES_ROOT_DIR="${SERVICES_ROOT_DIR}"
  WORKSPACE="${WORKSPACE}"
  VERBOSE=false

  # Help function
  print_help() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [OPTION]..."
    echo "Options:"
    echo "  --services_root [path] Set the root directory for services (default set in docker-compose.yml)"
    echo "  --workspace [name]     Set the workspace name (default set in docker-compose.yml)"
    echo "  -v, --verbose          Enable verbose mode (optional)"
    echo "  -h, --help             Display this help message"
  }

  # Add a case for the help option in the while loop
  # Parse command-line arguments
  while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
  do
    case "$1" in
      --workspace)
        WORKSPACE="$2"
        shift
        shift
        ;;
      --services_root)
        SERVICES_ROOT_DIR="$2"
        shift
        shift
        ;;
      -v| --verbose)
        VERBOSE=true
        shift
        ;;
      -h| --help)
        print_help
        exit 0
        ;;
      *)
        ;;
    esac
  done

  if [ "$VERBOSE" = true ] ; then
    set +e -x
  fi

  # Use the values
  echo "SERVICES_ROOT_DIR: $SERVICES_ROOT_DIR"
  echo "WORKSPACE: $WORKSPACE"
  echo "VERBOSE: $VERBOSE"

  # ensure SERVICE_ROOT_DIR and WORKSPACE are either set in the environment or passed as arguments
  if [[ -z "${SERVICES_ROOT_DIR}" || -z "${WORKSPACE}" ]]; then
      echo "Services_root_dir and workspace undefined."
      echo "usage: $0 --services_root <services_root_dir> --workspace <workspace_dir>"
      exit 1
  fi

  SETUP_FOLDER_PATH="$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))"

  generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement() {
    TELECOM=$1
    SUBSCRIBER_ID=$2
    ACCOUNT_ID=$3
    CREATE_TIME=$4
    MSISDN=$5
    CARDINALITY=$6

    STATEMENT="INSERT INTO dcp.um_subscribers (
        subscriber_id,
        operator,
        primary_account_id,
        create_time,
        external_id,
        port_in_telco,
        properties,
        state,
        cardinality
    ) VALUES (
        '${SUBSCRIBER_ID}',
        '${TELECOM}',
        '${ACCOUNT_ID}',
        '${CREATE_TIME}',
        '${MSISDN}',
        '',
        '',
        2,
        ${CARDINALITY}
    );

    INSERT INTO dcp.um_cardinality_reverse_index (
        cardinality,
        operator_name,
        subscriber_id
    ) VALUES (
        ${CARDINALITY},
        '${TELECOM}',
        '${SUBSCRIBER_ID}'
    );

    INSERT INTO dcp.um_accounts (
        account_id,
        primary_subscribers,
        billing_day_of_month,
        operator,
        properties,
        state
    ) VALUES (
        '${ACCOUNT_ID}',
        { '${SUBSCRIBER_ID}' },
        25,
        '${TELECOM}',
        '{}',
        2
    );

    INSERT INTO dcp.um_external_id_subscriber_map (
        external_id,
        operator,
        subscriber_id
    ) VALUES (
        '${MSISDN}',
        '${TELECOM}',
        '${SUBSCRIBER_ID}'
    );"

    echo "${STATEMENT}" >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
  }

  # IMPORTANT NOTE:
  # Don't forget to adjust cardinality counters in redis initialization script!
  # Otherwise, additional subscribers, registered during integration tests, would have overlapping cardinality!
  # In case of changes to subscriber_id and/or cardinality, check if redis initialization script needs to be updated too.

  generate_cassandra_subscribers() {
    # Avantel subscribers
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "avantel" "d9637f31599f4c0c8c32c057e762bdd3" "6e4f66d42d4a43b693d1813b97216f93" "2018-11-06 18:10:08" "573192238619" 1

    # LotusFlareTelecom subscribers
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "lotusflaretelecom" "ee00a6008bd145ae98b1147de6f1c5aa" "d825fbd9782b4b73b0e4fd3995a0247a" "2018-11-06 18:10:11" "573192238621" 1
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "lotusflaretelecom" "355301000756453aa72f088c16857cb5" "623f05346d754ae4967cd8a999f7d6c6" "2018-11-06 18:10:12" "573192238622" 2
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "lotusflaretelecom" "b14c036de7c344dba30d9b2f288e823c" "d77cff5e8f714ff6a89ce5f0a5a42a28" "2018-11-06 18:10:13" "573192238623" 3
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "lotusflaretelecom" "d966ac496dae4d00a351317de6ad8ec3" "f1a53f0ea4ca477498d14845a278984b" "2018-11-06 18:10:14" "573192238624" 4
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "lotusflaretelecom" "a830b4507af643c295e4e993346be4a0" "e76f84a4c51c40a09de585b5a4e6964d" "2018-11-06 18:10:15" "573192238625" 5
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "lotusflaretelecom" "062965e6e11e4ae8b9c2a92b18dc8e60" "4be89afcd57b11ebb8bc0242ac130003" "2018-11-06 18:10:16" "573192238626" 6
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "lotusflaretelecom" "d9637f31599f4c0c8c32c057e762bdd3" "6e4f66d42d4a43b693d1813b97216f93" "2018-11-06 18:10:17" "573192238627" 7

    #project8 subscribers
    generate_cassandra_add_subscriber_statement "project8" "d9637f31599f4c0c8c32c057e762bdd3" "6e4f66d42d4a43b693d1813b97216f93" "2018-11-06 18:10:08" "573192238619" 1
  }

  generate_test_data() {

    #Youtube TV Voucher Setup
    STATEMENT="INSERT INTO catalog.entity_master (
      operator_name,
      type,
      id,
      data,
      name,
      portal_id,
      version,
      state
    ) VALUES (
      'pilotfiber',
      'product',
      '69d08351f7ba4f61bb89e821f1e61c26',
      '{\"terms_and_conditions\":{\"en\":\"youtube tv\"},\"voucher_settings\":{\"use_type\":\"external\",\"assignment_type\":\"internal\"},\"description\":{\"en\":\"youtube tv\"},\"name\":{\"en\":\"youtube tv\"},\"voucher_type\":\"unique\",\"type\":\"voucher_set\"}',
      'Youtube TV Voucher Set',
      '13',
      1,
      2
    );"
    echo "${STATEMENT}" >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"

    STATEMENT="INSERT INTO vouchers.unique_voucher_codes_batch (
      operator_name,
      voucher_set_id,
      first_voucher_code_id,
      batch_length,
      last_voucher_code_id,
      load_time,
      status
    ) VALUES (
      'pilotfiber',
      '69d08351f7ba4f61bb89e821f1e61c26',
      8c4bffbc-4dd5-11ec-9193-0242ac140008,
      2,
      8c4d4084-4dd5-11ec-9193-0242ac140008,
      1637834011,
      1
    );"
    echo "${STATEMENT}" >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"

    STATEMENT="INSERT INTO vouchers.voucher_code_batch_added (
      operator_name,
      voucher_set_id,
      batch_added_id,
      add_end_time,
      add_start_time,
      added_count,
      skipped_count,
      status
    ) VALUES (
      'pilotfiber',
      '69d08351f7ba4f61bb89e821f1e61c26',
      8c4bffbc-4dd5-11ec-9193-0242ac140008,
      1637841311,
      1637841311,
      1,
      0,
      'done'
    );"
    echo "${STATEMENT}" >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"

    STATEMENT="INSERT INTO vouchers.voucher_code_ids (
      operator_name,
      voucher_set_id,
      voucher_code_id,
      voucher_code
    ) VALUES (
      'pilotfiber',
      '69d08351f7ba4f61bb89e821f1e61c26',
      8c4bffbc-4dd5-11ec-9193-0242ac140008,
      '8418136786885'
    );"
    echo "${STATEMENT}" >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"

    STATEMENT="INSERT INTO vouchers.voucher_set_codes (
      operator_name,
      voucher_set_id,
      voucher_code,
      created_time,
      voucher_code_id
    ) VALUES (
      'pilotfiber',
      '69d08351f7ba4f61bb89e821f1e61c26',
      '8418136786885',
      1637841311,
      8c4bffbc-4dd5-11ec-9193-0242ac140008
    );"
    echo "${STATEMENT}" >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
    #End Youtube TV Voucher Setup
  }

  update_cassandra_data() {
    find ${SERVICES_ROOT_DIR} -name keyspace_dev.cql | xargs cat >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
    find ${SERVICES_ROOT_DIR} -name schema.cql | xargs cat >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
    find ${SERVICES_ROOT_DIR} -name alter.cql | xargs cat >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
    find /lua/cassandra_setup -iname "*.cql" | xargs cat >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"

    python3 /lua/cassandra_setup/billingv4_rules.py --docker true >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"

    generate_cassandra_subscribers
    generate_test_data
    while ! cqlsh dd_cassandra -e 'describe cluster' ; do
        echo "waiting for dd_cassandra to be up..."
        sleep .5
    done
    cqlsh dd_cassandra -f "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
    echo "AFTER cqlsh"
  }

  update_cassandra_data
```

How can I dig deeper to find what went wrong here? There's not enough information to deduce from the logs to move in any direction forward.

Edit: After a bit more debugging, I found that adding the **echo "AFTER cqlsh"** just after the **cqlsh dd_cassandra -f "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"** command seems to make the cassandra_populator container exit with status 0, on removing that echo statement, the container exits with status 2.

What could be the reason for that to happen?

**EDIT:**

Seems like there's some cassandra command in the `schema.cql` that's causing the script to exit with status 2. I confirmed this with commenting the below 2 lines in the cassandra script and then the script succeeds with status 0.

```
find ${SERVICES_ROOT_DIR} -name schema.cql | xargs cat >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
find ${SERVICES_ROOT_DIR} -name alter.cql | xargs cat >> "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might not be directly related to Docker Compose's `condition: service_completed_successfully`, but rather how the `cassandra_populator` service's script (`cassandra-setup.sh`) is executing and exiting.
The behavior where adding an `echo` command changes the exit status of the script hints at a potential issue with how the script's exit status is determined.

The exit status of a script on Linux is typically the exit status of the last command executed in the script, unless an explicit `exit` command is provided with a specific exit code. That means if the last command before the script ends is `cqlsh dd_cassandra -f "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"` and if [`cqlsh`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html) encounters any issue or for some reason does not exit cleanly, it could potentially cause the script to exit with a non-zero status (which is not `0`). Adding an `echo` after `cqlsh` makes sure the last command executed is `echo`, which almost certainly exits with a status `0`; hence the script exits "successfully".

Of course, to make sure the script exits with a status `0` regardless of the commands before it, you can explicitly add an `exit 0` at the end of your script. That makes sure your script signals successful execution to Docker Compose.

```bash
  # At the end of cassandra-setup.sh
  exit 0
```

But a more robust approach would be, before concluding the script, to verify the success of the `cqlsh` command. You can capture its exit status and act accordingly. For example:

```bash
cqlsh dd_cassandra -f "${WORKSPACE}/schema.cql"
CQLSH_EXIT_STATUS=$?

if [ $CQLSH_EXIT_STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "cqlsh command failed with status $CQLSH_EXIT_STATUS"
    exit $CQLSH_EXIT_STATUS
else
    echo "cqlsh command succeeded"
    exit 0
fi
```

If you are still facing issues, [increase the verbosity of the `cqlsh` command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43606268/6309) (if possible) to get more insights into why it might fail or not exit cleanly. That can help in identifying if there are issues with the Cassandra queries themselves or with the connectivity to the `dd_cassandra` service.

---

> That kind of narrowed down the debugging process.
> I found that the `schema.cql` file that I'm generating inside the `cassandra-setup.sh` bash script has some errors - probably some cql commands are incorrect.
> Any idea how I should check if a cql file has the correct set of commands?

`cqlsh` does not seem to have a built-in dry-run mode. However, you can simulate this by running `cqlsh` in a manner that minimizes side effects. For example, you could connect to a test keyspace or a temporary Cassandra instance and run your script there. That will not check the syntax without execution, but it will allow you to see if the commands execute successfully in a non-production environment.

Some Integrated Development Environments (IDEs) and code editors have plugins or extensions that support CQL syntax highlighting and basic validation. For example, [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/apache-cassandra.html) by JetBrains, or [extensions available for Visual Studio Code](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/tools/visualstudioworkbench/), may offer syntax highlighting that can help identify errors.
While not as common as validators for languages like SQL, you might find online tools designed to validate CQL syntax. For instance, [OneCompiler / Cassandra](https://onecompiler.com/cassandra).

Use tools that can mock Cassandra's behavior to test your CQL scripts ([cdata QueryQurge](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-jdbc-querysurge.rst)). Tools like [`Simulacron`](https://github.com/datastax/simulacron) can simulate Cassandra clusters and allow you to run your CQL scripts without affecting real data.
Set up a CI/CD pipeline that runs your CQL scripts against a test Cassandra instance. That can help catch errors in the CI phase before deployment.

For existing tables and schemas, you can use [Cassandra's `DESCRIBE` command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlshDescribe.html) to print the schema of the keyspace or table. That can be useful for verifying that your CQL commands have the intended effect:

```bash
cqlsh -e "DESCRIBE KEYSPACE mykeyspace"
```

That would show the current schema, which you can compare against the expected schema changes your script is supposed to make.

Modify your script to log output and errors from `cqlsh`. That can help identify exactly where and why a failure occurs:

```bash
cqlsh -f "/path/to/schema.cql" > /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1
```

That command redirects both standard output and standard error to a logfile, which you can review for errors.

Comment: Thanks! that kind of narrowed down the debugging process. I found that the schema.cql file that I'm generating inside the cassandra-setup.sh bash script has some errors - probably some cql commands are incorrect. Any idea how should I check if a cql file has correct set of commands?